# Navigation link structure: two templates, two channels, one category group?

Tags: categories, category-group

I have a navigation/URL structure issue, and I haven't been able to find online exactly what I want to accomplish.

I have an "About" template and a "Staff" template - so different URL's for each template.
I have two Channels, one for each template, but have only ONE category group.

I've set up the navigation so that I have a drop-down under my "about" navigation item, which lists all of the categories - About, Mission, Staff, Facts.
All of the categories, except for Staff, will pull up on the "About" template.  I want "Staff," however, to direct to my staff template.  Is this possible?

What variable do I use to direct that one category to another template?

I have this code in my nav:

```
{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" style="linear" show_empty="no"}
                <li><a href="{path='??'}">{category_name}</a></li>
            {/exp:channel:categories}
```

[image: Navigation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general using categories for navigation on "static" sections can be frustrating. They weren't really designed with that in mind.

In this case I'd try using a conditional inside the loop to look for the staff entry and then build a different link:

```
{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" style="linear" show_empty="no"}
        <li>
            {if category_url_title != "staff"}
                <a href="{path='about/index'}">{category_name}</a>
            {/if}

            {if category_url_title=="staff"}
                <a href="{site_url}about/staff'}">{category_name}</a>
            {/if}

        </li>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

The reason for not using the path linking variable in the second case is that because it's within a category loop EE will create a category link (http://yoursite.com/about/staff/category/category_url_title) which in this case you don't want.